# jquery datepicker out of css scope

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using multiple ui themes in one page. I create a custom theme with a `css` scope, lets say `#scope`. I use a datepicker field in the scope lets say `#scope input#datepicker`. the datepicker field does not get `css` styles from the the ui theme. I guess this is because it is dynamically created outside of `#scope`, how can I alter this, and how can make it to get styles from scoped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem with adding a wrapper div in code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ui-datepicker-div").wrap('<div class="ui-layout-center" />');
});
```

Comment: Just to clarify the "ui-layout-center" is your custom css class, is that right? I'd personally try to avoid using the same ui- prefix as is used in the rest of jQuery UI to avoid possible name collisions in future versions.

Answer (score 2):

@bkilinc, you are correct. The datepicker calendar is appended to document.body, outside of your custom scope.

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4591 
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4306

In a structure like the following, the calendar is outside of the scope of the container.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .calendarContainer .ui-datepicker {
        /* rule intended to affect only .calendarContainer */
    }
</style>
...
<body>
    <div class="calendarContainer"><input name="date"/></div>
    <div class="ui-datepicker"> (generated calendar)</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember having the same problem, check the style defined in general such as `span`, it may overlap with `ui` styles.